# If I am in gnome and I click logout from the menu during a VNC session, how do I get back in?

Tags: gnome, centos, vnc

I am running a CentOS server. I made an SSH tunnel and used VNC to connect to my server. Then after I was done doing some 'things' I clicked logout from the gnome menu. Well I didn't actually leave, instead everything went away except for the background and the bash window. However I can't figure out what command will bring everything back. Even if I close the SSH and re-connect and re-VNC back in, everything is still the same.

How do I log back into gnome?

Comment: If your server is configured to auto log-in and is connected to a monitor (i.e. a gnome session is started on boot), you could just reboot the server it from an SSH session.

Comment: @jozzas Yes I have determined that rebooting the server works, but this is not a solution. There has got to be a command to 'log back in'.